I'm getting a different server key when i try to log in to the same ip address using an alias
I logged into a remote server using my username via ssh using the ip address  ssh user@ipaddress
Got the following server key which is in my known_hosts file and in the server's public key file:
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIML0EFwYit1Z/zUQx3kUsUxpS0Masdizyl36UGDrXP3W

which has the following sha256sum:
user@computer:~$ sha256sum /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
cc86691095b2e5a76e96744a30520f71a14c90a4a07c294a5b9c7ce1cf4cb176  /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub

I wanted to create an alias for it so I added the following configurations to my ~/.ssh/config file:
Host wiki
  HostName SameIPAddress
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  ServerAliveInterval 120
  ServerAliveCountMax 30

When i tried to log in with the alias cmd ssh user@wiki
I got the following server key:
The authenticity of host 'SameIPAddress (SameIPAddress)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:nRNi8asPrzCz0HMraA3e9qyQbT37J+3/e5HVaovhCNmM.

I would think that if I'm logging into the same server with the same keys but a different alias i should get the same sha256 sum for the key that i got when i logged in with the IP address.
I would appreciate some insight on some reasons for why I'm seeing a different key when I attempt to log in with an alias :)

Are you running OpenSSH 8.5 or higher on the client, or have CheckHostIP no configured? Older OpenSSH defaulted CheckHostIP yes which means it stored both hostname and IPaddr in known_hosts, so using a different name for the same IPaddr would find and use the already-known key. On recent OpenSSH you can explicitly reenable this behavior if you want it. However for the key you posted I get CxBo1OwWLH9WIHeGZmoUSGgcvywUwaHeuG2P/Q2hHEI not nRNi8asPrzCz0HMraA3e9qyQbT37J+3/e5HVaovhCNmM !

The SHA256 fingerprint of the key is not equal to the SHA256 sum of the file that contains it.
Run ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key on the server to find the SHA256 sum of the key.

Or if a masochist, cut -d' ' -f2 pubkeyfile | base64 -d | sha256sum | xxd -r -p | base64 | sed 's/=*$//'
